# iPad crashing when linking with CoreVideo or CoreMedia

Tags: iphone

I have an application that runs fine on the simulator.

When trying to run on the actual iPhone, I get link errors that require the CoreVideo and CoreMedia frameworks - and then the application runs fine on the iPhone hardware and the iPhone simulator.

Unfortunately, as soon as I do that, the application crashes on the iPad simulator (and according to some report - on the iPad hardware too) - until I REMOVE the CoreMedia and CoreVideo frameworks... But then again it doesn't link for the iPhone hardware.

Catch 22...

I searched the internet high-and-low, but found no answer.
I tried weak-linking to these frameworks, but is still didn't help - the iPad simulator crashes like mad...

Is there maybe a way to add a framework to a specific application?

**EDIT** 
Based on Michal's comment, here's some more information.
1. I need these libraries for the h/w, in order to successfully link with the ZXing QR code scanning widget.
2. The iPad version of my software crashes as soon as it launches with the following error:

**Attaching to process 73137.
dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
  Referenced from: /Users/admin/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/3.2/Applications/CF1E8FD0-3E84-495F-B2CB-3A2BF5F1F916/myappname.app/myappname
 
 Reason: image not found**

**EDIT**

Thanks,

Comment: Your information is insufficient. What's the reason for CoreVideo/Media frameworks ? You either need them or not, doesn't matter what platform. Where does it crash on the iPad ? You can search internet high and low, but if you can't ask proper question, there's no answer to be found out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CoreVideo and CoreMedia are only available on iOS 4.0 and above. I presume the iPad simulator version you're trying to run is iPhone OS 3.2? If so it will crash unless you weak leak those frameworks and put appropriate conditional code checks around code that uses them.

Comment: Chris, everything you say makes lots of sense... Alas, I did weak link and conditionally call the code... So I'm looking for other ideas. Reuven

Comment: Attaching to process 73137. dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia Referenced from: /Users/admin/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/3.2/Applications/CF1E8FD0-3E84-495F-B2CB-3A2BF5F1F916/myappname.app/myappname 
Reason: image not found

Comment: In that case, that suggests that the CoreMedia framework is not weakly linked. If it were your app would not be trying to load the library on start up before your main. Can you confirm what the library's type is set to in your Target's Linked Libraries section?

Comment: Chris, I've placed a copy of a plain-vanilla project, created from scratch as a universal iOS application at the following link: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1593063/iPadCrashLink.zip . It shows the fact the libraries are defined as weak-link. Please point out what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: That looks like a slightly different issue: dyld: Symbol not found: _CFXMLNodeGetInfoPtr. Seems to be something that is not implemented in the Security.framework on the simulator. Appears to run fine on a device.

Comment: question is whether there's anything to do about it or simply grump - since i did weak-link...

Comment: This is highlighted as an issue in the release notes for iOS 4.2. At this stage, it would appear the only option would be to use the 4.2 simulator or a 3.2 device for testing.

Comment: Anyone know if the iOS 4.2 released SDK fixes this problem?

Comment: UPDATE: using iOS 4.2 SDK, this doesn't crash on simulator for iPad 4.2 - but still crashes on simulator for iPad 3.2

Answer (score 1):

As it has been mentioned above, CoreVideo and CoreMedia are only available on iOS 4.0. If you want to use libraries that are not available in 3.X iOS, you have to do something called weak linking, you have to make those frameworks optional in the project and make sure that the classes that are using them are not gonna be called in your app if you running iOS version lower than 4.0

Comment: Thanks. I did weak-link (as my first comment stated :-(). Though since I moved to a newer version of Xcode, the problem disappeared.